# Can I display material design Snackbar in dialog?

Tags: android, material-design, android-snackbar

I am developing an android application. In that I want to display material design Snackbar in dialog. Is it possible? If yes then how?

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: technically speaking, it should be a problem. The real question is why would one need that

Comment: I don't think you can use Snackbar in dialog because it always display on the bottom of the screen. In addition, you shouldn't use Snackbar in dialog I must say because it's not the right way to use of it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's definitely possible, you just have to pass the View of the Dialog to the `SnackBar`.

**Example**

```
    AlertDialog.Builder mAlertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    // inflate the custom dialog view
    final View mDialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);
    // set the View for the AlertDialog
    mAlertDialogBuilder.setView(mDialogView);

    Button btn = (Button) mDialogView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Pass the mDialogView to the SnackBar
            Snackbar
                    .make(mDialogView, "SnackBar in Dialog", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alertDialog = mAlertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
```

**Result**

[image: picture showing result]

**Note**:
There's no need to use a `CoordinatorLayout` as the root. In my example I simply used a LinearLayout as the root.

Comment: Swiping SnackBar may not be possible when not using CoordinatorLayout.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can.

To show `Snackbar` inside your `Dialog` create custom `View` for it. You can read more about it here: [Dialogs/Creating a Custom Layout](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)

Then for showing `Snackbar` invoke `Snackbar.make((dialogView, "text", duration))` where `dialogView` is your custom view.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a `Dialog` then:

```
dialog_share = new Dialog(MainScreen.this, R.style.DialogTheme);
dialog_share.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
mDialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_share, null);
dialog_share.setContentView(mDialogView);
dialog_share.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.translucent_black);
dialog_share.show();

public void ShowSnackBarNoInternetOverDialog() {
        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(mDialogView, getString(R.string.checkinternet), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
        snackbar.setActionTextColor(Color.CYAN);
        snackbar.setAction("OK", new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Toast.makeText(MainScreen.this, "snackbar OK clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        snackbar.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `getDialog().getWindow().getDecorView()` inside Snackbar.make()

```
Snackbar
      .make(getDialog().getWindow().getDecorView(), "SnackBar in Dialog", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
      .show();
```