# How to add a SnackBar on the bottom of a dialog's overlay

Tags: android, dialog, snackbar

I have an android application which has many different pop-ups. I want to add a `SnackBar` over dialog's overlay on the bottom of the screen.

I tried the following code

```
if (fragment!= null) {
    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(fragment.getDialog().getWindow().findViewById(android.R.id.content),
            message, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
    View view = snackbar.getView();
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params =(FrameLayout.LayoutParams)view.getLayoutParams();
    params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
    view.setLayoutParams(params);
    snackbar.show();
}
```

But the `SnackBar` appears on the bottom of centered `Dialog` not on the bottom of the screen. If I add the `Snackbar` on current `Activity` then it appears under dialog's overlay.

[image: Android SnackBar]

Comment: Use custom dialog with custom layout which has match_parent height and try to set that layout's background to transparent to have same feeling as android's default dialog.

Comment: The dialog from above picture already has values of width and height set to `match_parent`

Comment: I have edited my answer, could you check

Answer (score 5):

You are parsing Dialog view as

`fragment.getDialog().getWindow().findViewById(android.R.id.content)`

I suggest you to parse fragment layout root view instead.

Comment: Should I add an `id` to my top layout component and then pass it to `SnackBar` using `findViewById(R.id.my_dialog_parent_component_id)`?

Comment: Thats what I meant

Answer (score 5):

Use below theme for full screen custom dialog

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">

<item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
<item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>


<!-- No backgrounds, titles or window float -->
<item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
```

Use it in your dialog as below:

```
dialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.DialogTheme);
```

To use above things, you should use custom layout for your custom dialog.

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

Try above line to make your dialog background transparent.

Comment: I tried your solution but in this case dialog will have the same height as the display and I want that the `Dialog` to have `wrap_content` for height. To solve this I tried to add a new `RelativeLayout` to my resource layout and make it transparent but it seems that its background is white.

Comment: @roroinpho21 I've edited my ans, pls check if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your quick replay. Now it is almost what I want. When I click on transparent zone I would like to `dismiss` the dialog in this moment nothing happens. I think I should add an `onCLick` event as workaround Also I would like, if it is possible, to replace the transparent color with a transparent black as it can be seen in the picture from my post.

Answer (score 2):

Here `LayoutInflater.inflate` is used instead. Try to map the code as you need.
[Here you can find more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32454701/can-i-display-material-design-snackbar-in-dialog)

```
 AlertDialog.Builder mAlertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
// inflate the custom dialog view
final View mDialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);
// set the View for the AlertDialog
mAlertDialogBuilder.setView(mDialogView);

Button btn = (Button) mDialogView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_btn);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // Pass the mDialogView to the SnackBar
        Snackbar
                .make(mDialogView, "SnackBar in Dialog", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
});
AlertDialog alertDialog = mAlertDialogBuilder.create();
alertDialog.show();
```

If you need a help to map it to your code, feel free to ask

Comment: In this case the `Snackbar` appears at the bottom of the dialog not at the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I think I have done what you expect. even i have added few answers to this same question, I add this answer as a separate answer to be more clear to you.

[image]

Its dirty UI, I prepared it very rushy. Can You see the `StackBar` At the bottom of the screen. It displays when you click on the `OK` button of the `AlertDialog`

Here is how I did it.

following code belongs to `custom_dialog_layout.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:text="Sample Test for Custom Dialog"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/image" />/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/dialogButtonOK"
    android:layout_width="100px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=" Ok "
    android:layout_below="@+id/text"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

following code belongs to `activity_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:id="@+id/rootView"
tools:context="com.stackoverflow.answer.androidcustomdialog.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!" />
```

following code belongs to `MainActivity.java`

```
package com.stackoverflow.answer.androidcustomdialog;

import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final View rootView=(View)findViewById(R.id.rootView);

    AlertDialog.Builder mAlertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    // inflate the custom dialog view
    LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
    final View mDialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog_layout, null);
    // set the View for the AlertDialog
    mAlertDialogBuilder.setView(mDialogView);

    Button btn = (Button) mDialogView.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Pass the RootView to the SnackBar
            Snackbar
                    .make(rootView, "SnackBar in Dialog", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alertDialog = mAlertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
}
```

Feel free to ask anything you need. In this example I haven't use fragments. If you need I can help with that too. and also I can send the project if you need. give me your email :)

**As a summary, What I have really did is, just pass the RooT Layout View to the `SnackBar`.** Its simple as that.

One More Thing..

According to the [Google Material Design Snackbars & Toasts Usage](https://material.google.com/components/snackbars-toasts.html#snackbars-toasts-usage) Reference

> Placement
>
> Snackbars appear above most elements on screen, and they are equal in
>   elevation to the floating action button. However, they are lower in
>   elevation than dialogs, bottom sheets, and navigation drawers.

So the Snackbar will always appear lower level in elevation than dialogs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I want is to put the `Snackbar` over `Dialog` but as you shown me in your post the `Snackbar` will always appear lower level in elevation than dialogs.

Comment: I think You can mark this as correct answer, isn't it

Comment: Well, no offence, but It is yes and no. Yes because I gave up to put the `Snackbar` over dialog and no because if someone wants to have the `Snackbar` over dialog overlay this code snippet won't help.

Comment: this isn't at all what was requested

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution:
Used material dialog :
custom_dialog_layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:text="Sample Test for Custom Dialog"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/image" />/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/dialogButtonOK"
    android:layout_width="100px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=" Ok "
    android:layout_below="@+id/text"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

fragment.java

```
    final MaterialDialog dialog = new MaterialDialog.Builder(context)
                .customView(R.layout.custom_dialog_layout, false)
                .positiveText(R.string.btn_OK)
                .canceledOnTouchOutside(false)

                .negativeText(android.R.string.cancel)
                .onPositive(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(@NonNull final MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
Snackbar.make(mCoordinatorLayout, "Please Enter All fields!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                    dialog.show();
})

                .build()
 positiveAction = dialog.getActionButton(DialogAction.POSITIVE);
  mCoordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) dialog.getCustomView().getRootView().findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout);
 dialog.show();
```